# Submit 2 forms with one click button

Tags: forms, wordpress, authentication, submit

I have 2 forms . one for log in to wordpress and another for login to a flash based chat.
the flash based chat use wordpress accounts to log in users.
i want to mix these 2 forms together. when user click on submit button login to wordpress and chat same time.

This is chat login form:

```
    <form action="http://www.domain.com/1chat.php" method="post" target="mychat1" onsubmit="window.open('', 'mychat1', 'width=800,height=600,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no')">

<input type="text" name="username">

<input type="password" name="password">

<input type="submit" value="">
```

and this is wordpress login form:

```
<form id="wp_login_form" action="" method="post">
<label>Username</label><br />
<input type="text" name="username" class="text" value="" /><br />
<label>Password</label><br />
<input type="password" name="password" class="text" value="" /> <br />
<label>
<input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" value="forever" />Remember me</label>
<input type="submit" id="submitbtn" name="submit" value="Login" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to submit multiple HTML form at the same time. But y see several workarounds :

- You can embed the chat login form into an iframe (on the same domain to avoid [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) troubles), displayed (but maybe hidden via CSS) into the wordpress login page. Using jQuery, you can submit it when submitting the login form. This way, the two forms will be submitted at the same time seamlessly.
  See this example : http://jsbin.com/ivaluv/1/edit
- Maybe you can submit the chat login form via AJAX (POST), but I'm not sure because of a bunch of built-in security rules used by web browsers.

Here is how to submit a form into an iframe from the parent (login form) using jQuery :

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#wp_login_form').submit(function(e){
        var chat_login_window = $('#chat_login_iframe').contentWindow;
        chat_login_window.jQuery('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. but i need to login to chat and wordpress same time when i click on button. also i have to say: the chat users system is base on wordpress accounts . if you attention to the codes in question you will see how forms work.